# Using replace in Angular directive

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-directive

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[mpnAadharDirective]'
})
export class GeneralDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('keyup') keyup() {
    console.log(this.el.nativeElement.value.replace(/\d(?=\d{4})/g, "*"))
  }
}
```

With the above code I'm trying to replace the nativeElement value, but I get the value printed but it is not replacing. I need some help in fixing this.
Thank you.

Comment: the `replace: true` flag had come up with more problems than solutions which is why it was removed. therefore you can not build `directives` in such a way anymore and provide valid html markup. The only workaround is to use an `attribute-directive` instead:

Comment: Thank you, should we use @input as workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing event target value should works:

```
@HostListener('keyup', ['$event']) keyup(event) {
  event.target['value'] = this.el.nativeElement.value.replace(/\d(?=\d{4})/g, "*");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. When I console this out, it's only printing the values I type and not replacing. That's the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure about your problem, [this is a small Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7yevqf), it seems to work.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I had some issue with ngx mask which was interfering.